# Selecting an attribute value with XPath in Google Spreadsheet with multiple similar named attributes

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to select the value of an attribute in Google Spreadsheets for a board game's rank.

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/127023?stats=1

under //boardgames/boardgame/statistics/ratings/ranks/ there are two nodes called "rank"

The first one has type='subtype' and is the one I want to return the value in the 'value' attribute (which at the time of writing this was '67'.

I'm trying this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/127023?stats=1", "//boardgames/boardgame/statistics/ratings/ranks/rank[@value]")
```

Which doesn't work. (Imported content is empty).

I can select the value in nodes fine, for example:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/boardgame/127023?stats=1", "//boardgames/boardgame/statistics/ratings/average")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the value of attribute `value` add a slash before `@value`.

```
"//boardgames/boardgame/statistics/ratings/ranks/rank/[@value]"
```

Note that the above xpath will return 2 values i.e. 67 and 47.

If you want to fetch only the `rank` where `type="subtype"` then you can use the following xpath:

```
"//boardgames/boardgame/statistics/ratings/ranks/rank[@type='subtype']/@value"
```